# How can a script check if it's being run as root?

Tags: bash, scripts, root

I'm writing a simple bash script, but I need it to check whether it's being run as root or not. I know there's probably a very simple way to do that, but I have no idea how.

Just to be clear:
What's a simple way to write a script *foo.sh*, so that the command `./foo.sh` outputs `0`, and the command `sudo ./foo.sh` outputs `1`?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I'm accepting this one cause (after some testing) using the system variable EUID turned out to be (approx 100 times) faster than running a command (id -u), but all of the answers worked great.

Comment: Thanks aneeshep. I didn't even know there was an environment variable for the effective UID.

Comment: Be careful though! A program can *temporarily* drop its superuser privileges in which case `$UID` and `id -ru` are still 0, but `$EUID` and `id -u` aren't. See [`getuid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getuid) and decide what you need.

Comment: Also, `$UID` and `$EUID` are bashisms. Merely POSIX compliant shells don't have those variables and you need to use [`id(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/id) instead.

Comment: in a bash script, you could use `if ((EUID)); then`, see [@geirha's comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15853/how-can-a-script-check-if-its-being-run-as-root#comment33736_30161)

Comment: -1. This does not meet the requirements of the question. Running `echo $EUID` as the first 'normal' user gives me `1000` (expected). Running `sudo echo $EUID` gives me `1000` (not expected). On the other hand, `id -u` gives me `1000`, and `sudo id -u` gives me `0` (both expected).

Comment: @Andrew: Variables are substituted before they are passed to `sudo`. If you run `sudo sh -c 'echo $EUID'` you will see your expected results.

Comment: @M.Dudley That makes sense. I would take back my downvote if I could. However, `sudo sh -c 'echo $EUID'` gives me a blank line. I should see `0`.

Comment: @Andrew – I know I'm way late here, but for posterity: `$EUID` is a Bashism (as mentioned above by @DavidFoerster), and your `/bin/sh` is most likely a link to `/bin/dash`, not `/bin/bash`. `sudo bash -c 'echo $EUID'` will yield the expected result.

Comment: @AdrianGünter Even if it's a link to `/bin/bash`, many (all?) Bash installs will run in POSIX mode if called as `sh`. That is, they'll intentionally ignore Bashisms. It's useful as a first-pass test if you're trying to write POSIX-compliant shell scripts, but can cause issues if you're using `sh -c` to delay interpolation.

Comment: Can also be used as one-liner like `[[ $EUID -ne 0 ]] && echo "non-root" || echo "root"`

Answer (score 154):

A root user does not have to be named "root". `whoami` returns the first username with user ID `0`. `$USER` contains the name of the logged in user, which can have user ID `0`, but have a different name.

The only reliable program to check whether the account is logged in as root, or not:

```
id -u
```

I use `-u` for the *effective* user ID, not `-r` for the *real* user ID. Permissions are [determined](http://rechner.lst.de/~okir/blackhats/node23.html) by the *effective* user ID, not the *real* one.

#### Tests

`/etc/passwd` contains the following usernames with user ID `0` in the given order:

```
rootx
root2
```

Logged in as `root2`, gives the next results:

- `whoami`: `rootx`
- `echo $USER`: `root2` (this returns an empty string if the program was started in an empty environment, e.g. `env -i sh -c 'echo $USER'`)
- `id -u`: `0`
  As you can see, the other programs failed in this check, only `id -u` passed.

The updated script would looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [ $(id -u) = 0 ]; then
   echo "I am not root!"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I always try to stay as POSIX compliant as possible, using `sh` (`dash`) as interpreter instead of `bash`. But good shot, saves another fork :)

Comment: After being out cold for a while, i came back and took a look.  Lekensteyn's method does indeed seem to be better.  His answer is now the new accepted answer.  +1 to you, Lekensteyn, esp. for getting that hard-to-get badge off of this question ;)

Comment: Thanks for waiting that long for accepting my question :D I got a Gold Populist badge and a bronze Nice Answer for this answer :) I wonder how this question got that popular, 345 views in a day!

Comment: I still love using this test: `[ -w /etc/shadow ]`. If that's true, you might as well be root. ;)

Comment: I've seen shorter versions, `[ -w / ]`. The idea remains the same. Note: in certain chroots, `[ -w /etc/shadow ]` will fail because `/etc/shadow` is non-existent, therefore the approach with `/` is preferred. A way better would checking the actual need for root permissions. If the script needs to write to `/etc/someconfig`, just check if that file is writable OR the file does not exist and `/etc` is writable.

Comment: Yes, this is a great answer

Answer (score 40):

As [@Lekensteyn said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30148/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-shellscript-runs-as-root-or-not/30157#30157) you should use effective user ID. You don't need to call `id -u` in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "You must be root to do this." 1>&2
   exit 100
fi
```

@geirha's suggestion from the comments uses arithmetic evaluation:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( EUID != 0 )); then
   echo "You must be root to do this." 1>&2
   exit 100
fi
```

Comment: In general one should use `((..))` for testing numbers, and `[[..]]` for testing strings and files, so I'd do `if (( EUID != 0 )); then` instead, or just `if ((EUID)); then`

Comment: @geirha: I've added your suggestion.

Comment: `EUID` should become `$EUID`. Instead of using `(( $EUID != 0 ))`, use `[ $EUID != 0 ]`. It will work with `dash` too.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: `EUID` works just fine. The question is tagged `bash` not `dash`. The command `env -i sh -c '[ $EUID != 0 ]'` fails, but `env -i bash -c '(( EUID != 0 ))'` works. btw, `dash` doesn't work for some non-ascii characters on Ubuntu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160125/how-to-create-a-non-ascii-file-using-redirection-with-sh-c It is 2011 and there are people who use other languages.

Comment: After looking back on this while being horribly bored, and testing, I am going to use this method as listed here with the `$EUID` stuff from this point forward.  I have changed the accepted answer as a result.

Comment: None of these examples work for me on 12.04. I either get `EUID: not found` or `[[: not found`. `[ $(id -u) = 0 ]` worked like a charm though.

Comment: @briankb:  the examples work. Make sure you use bash, not dash.

Answer (score 22):

You can accomplish this by using the `whoami` command, which returns the current user:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ `whoami` != 'root' ]
  then
    echo "You must be root to do this."
    exit
fi

...
```

Running the above will print `You must be root to do this.` if the current user is not `root`.

---

**Note:** an alternative in some cases is to simply check the `$USER` variable:

```
if [ $USER != 'root' ]
```

Comment: I'll take a look at the code, see if it doesn’t make the script fail or something.  If it works, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Put this into my scripts, it worked beautifully.  Thanks much.  :)

Comment: @George Edison: I recommend against using `$USER`, especially in this way. `$USER` is set by the login shell, it does not necessary propagate to the program (`env -i sh -c 'echo $USER'`). In that way, `$USER` is empty and an syntax error occurs.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Not only is `$USER` set by the shell, it is also something that is easy to spoof. Whoami will return the actual user.

Comment: @PauldeVrieze What's the point of fooling that check?

Comment: `id -u` is a far superior solution. I believe this answer is potentially misleading and should not have been accepted.

Comment: `andrew@andrew-testing:~$ sudo whoami`
`root`
`andrew@andrew-testing:~$ sudo echo $USER`
`andrew`

Comment: @Sam: How is it misleading?

Comment: @andrewsomething: `$USER` is interpreted by your shell, your example should be `sudo sh -c 'echo $USER'` in order to be meaningful. @George: it makes the wrong assumption that `whoami` will always return `root` for UID 0.

Answer (score 13):

Taking efficiency into consideration, you may test, first, the `EUID` environment variable and then, if it doesn't exist, call the standard `id` command:

```
if ((${EUID:-0} || "$(id -u)")); then
  echo You are not root.
else
  echo Hello, root.
fi
```

This way, because of the *OR shortcut*, you avoid calling a system command, prioritizing the query of an in-memory variable.

Code reuse:

```
function amIRoot() {
  ! ((${EUID:-0} || "$(id -u)"))
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you haven't benchmarked it, well I have and this takes the very same time as `id -u`. See the bench script along with results below it here: https://pastebin.com/srC3LWQy

Comment: *`((${EUID:-0} || "$(id -u)"))` always runs `id -u`*, just as `((1 || $(echo hi >&2; echo 1)))` and `((0 || $(echo hi >&2; echo 1)))` both print `hi`. *Outside* shell arithmetic, `&&` and `||` are control operators; in `a || "$(b)"`, `b` only runs if `"$(b)"` runs. Most expansions, including command substitution, are governed by control operators' short-circuiting semantics. Shell arithmetic has operators that *happen* to be spelled `&&` and `||`, too--which also short-circuit in that `((1 || 0/0))` is not an error--but shell arithmetic occurs *after* nested command substitutions are expanded.

Answer (score 10):

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $(id -u) != 0 ]] 
echo $?
```

Comment: Numeric comparison is better done with `-ne` (counter-intuitive: text operands are for numeric comparison)

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(id -u)" == "0" ]
then
    echo "I am root."
else
    echo "I am not root."
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

This snippet would:

- Check on different sessions
- suggest to use `sudo !!`
- and return an error

```
if [ "$(whoami &2>/dev/null)" != "root" ] && [ "$(id -un &2>/dev/null)" != "root" ]
      then
      echo "You must be root to run this script!"
      echo "use 'sudo !!'"
      exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just to save an idea with may be helpful for some of you.
If you need script which is run from desktop GUI and requires root privileges try this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [ $(id -u) = 0 ]; then
   gksudo -w $0 $@
   exit
fi

#here go superuser commands, e.g. (switch intel cpu into powersave mode):
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
cpupower frequency-set -g powersave
```

This way you will get nice dialog window asking you for root user password. Just like with command-line sudo.

The `gksudo` may not be available in your system then install it with `sudo apt-get install gksu`.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to make the script only runnable by root is to start the script with the line:
`#!/bin/su root`

Comment: Don't do this. It attempts to log in directly as root, whereas sudo may be required on many systems because the former is forbidden. Furthermore, the shebang is intended to ensure your script runs in the one for which it was designed, whereas your method will cause the script to run in root's default shell, which cannot be predicted if the script is run by anyone other than the author. Therefore, using the shebang to elevate privileges of a script will severely break its portability and result in errors on many systems. (su: Authentication failure)

Comment: Don't do this. Some joker might create a second user named `root`, or make a user named `root` that isn't `root`, thereby fooling your program into thinking it's `root`. See https://askubuntu.com/a/836621/1070384.

Answer (score 1):

This code works under both Bash and stock Bourne sh (tested under FreeBSD) that does not define EUID. If EUID exists its value is returned, else the 'id' command is run. It is a tad shorter than the "or" example above, as it uses a shell built-in ":-".

Root in sh:

```
# echo $EUID

# euid=${EUID:-`id -u`}
# echo $euid
0

In bash:
[chaapala@tenfwd2 ese]$ euid=${EUID:-`id -u`}
[chaapala@tenfwd2 ese]$ echo $euid
10260
```

Comment: can you use the more modern `euid=${EUID:-$(id -u)}`

Comment: Yes, just as you have it there.