# How can I determine whether a shellscript runs as root or not?

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a script check if it’s being run as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15853/how-can-a-script-check-if-its-being-run-as-root)

This is something I've been curious about.  I make a lot of small bash scripts (.sh files) to do tasks that I routinely do.  Some of those tasks require everything to be ran as superuser.  I've been curious:  Is it possible to, within the BASH script prior to everything being run, check if the script is being run as superuser, and if not, print a message saying `You must be superuser to use this script`, then subsequently terminate the script itself.  The other side of that is I'd like to have the script run when the user **is** superuser, and not generate the error.

Any ideas on coding (if statements, etc.) on how to execute the aforementioned?