# Bash script to check whether a package is installed and if not, install it

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(Which gimp)" != ""]
then
{
  if [ "$(gimp -version)" != 2.8 ]
  then
{
sudo apt-get remove gimp
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
}
else 
  echo You already have gimp 2.8
fi  
}
else
{
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gimp
}
fi
```

I am trying to make a gimp 2.8 installer in Bash. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if [ "$(which gimp)" != ""]
```

`]` must be the `[` command's last argument, and it must be a separate argument, hence you need a space before it. See [Bash Pitfall 10](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bbar.3D.22.24foo.22.5D).

But, don't use `which`. It is a non-standard, external command that looks for a file in PATH. It behaves differently on different systems, and you can't really rely on a useful output or exit status. The shell already provides better ways of checking if a command exists and will work consistently on any system, so better learn those. See [Bash FAQ 81](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/081). In this case though, you don't need to test if gimp exists, just running `gimp -version`, or querying dpkg about the version of the gimp package (see [dpkg-query(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html)), will already tell you whether it exists or not.

```
if [ "$(gimp -version)" != 2.8 ]
```

AndAC already gave a solution for this one, but I'll provide another one; comparing the version numbers. dpkg provides a way to compare two versions, namely `dpkg --compare-versions ver1 op ver2`. E.g. `dpkg --compare-versions 2.6.12 '<' 2.8.0-1ubuntu0ppa6~precise` will return true since version 2.6.12 is older than 2.8.0-1ubuntu0ppa6~precise. See [dpkg(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dpkg.1.html).

All the brackets (`{` and `}`) in that script are pointless, they serve no purpose, so you might as well remove them.

Putting this all together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Query dpkg to get the version of the currently installed gimp package.
# The command returns false if the package is not installed.
if version=$(dpkg-query -W -f='${Version}' gimp 2>/dev/null); then 

    # Check if it's older than 2.8
    if dpkg --compare-versions "$version" '<' 2.8; then
        apt-get remove gimp || exit
    else
        printf 'Looks good.\n'
        exit
    fi
fi

add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp &&
apt-get update &&
apt-get install gimp
```

Answer (score 1):

First line, "which" is low-case:

```
if [ "$(which gimp)" != ""]
```

Here:

```
if [ "$(gimp -version)" != 2.8 ]
```

You can use:

```
gimp_ver=$(gimp -version)
gimp_ver=$(echo ${gimp_ver##* } | cut -f1-2 -d'.')
if [ $gimp_ver != "2.8" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of capturing the output and seeing if it's empty

```
if [ "$(which gimp)" != ""]
```

use this, which just considers the command's exit status (0 = success)

```
if which gimp &>/dev/null
then
```

Your use of braces to group commands is not necessary, but will not hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no information about what goes wrong it it is hard to help. But at the very least, you should fix the mis-spelling of "which", you have written it with a capital W and bash is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

A few technical observations and concerns you'll run into:

1. [Everything that @AndAC has said.](https://askubuntu.com/a/156852/10616)
2. `add-apt-repository` may not be installed on everyone's system.  On clean installations I've seen, 12.04 includes it by default but older ones do not.  You may want a stop at the beginning to do

   ```
   if [ "$(which add-apt-repository)" != ""]
   ```

   and in instances where it does not exist, force installation of the parent package as a dependency before continuing on in the script (note: omit sudo if you take the third bullet point in this list as part of your script): `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`
3. [You may want to utilize the methods described here to require your entire script to run as super user](https://askubuntu.com/a/30161/10616).  And I say this because on some systems, there is `sudoers` policy to require a passcode for *each and every instance* of the use of `sudo`.  I have a few scripts that needed that, and by adding in the information in the answer I linked, you can partially avoid that problem by requiring that you run the script as superuser (via `sudo`).