# How to require root privilege to run command or alias?

Tags: command-line

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I would like to force certain terminal commands to run as root - or at least require the user password - to execute.

For instance, `poweroff` requires `sudo` while `gnome-session-quit --logout` (which I have aliased as `logout`) does not.

How could I require `sudo` when running `logout` or any other command of my choosing?

Comment: Good question, can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: The [question I've closed this against](http://askubuntu.com/q/15853/) should get you there. You might have to switch from bash aliases to functions or scripts, but it'll do what you want.