# How to tell whether a bash script has root privileges

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that will only work with root privileges, so I want to test whether the user has them.  Other posts (see below) ask and answer how to know whether the user is actually running as `root`, but not whether the script has root privileges.  These posts say to test whether `$EUID` is 0.

To try this idea in the context of `sudo`, I wrote a bash script `/tmp/a.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $EUID
```

The following two commands were run as a non-root user with `sudo` privileges on Ubuntu 16.04. If the `$EUID` suggestion worked in the context of `sudo`, the second command would have printed 0 instead of a blank line.

```
$ /tmp/a.sh
1000
$ sudo /tmp/a.sh

$
```

FYI, an example of the related posts I am referencing is:

[How can a script check if it's being run as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15853/how-can-a-script-check-if-its-being-run-as-root)

Comment: `echo $UID` should work.  Or according to David F in the comments of your linked answer you should use `echo $(id -u)`

Comment: Thanks Terrance, that works too.  I posted an answer after noticing a fat-finger that causes $EUID and $UID to resolve properly only for non-root users (still a bit of a mystery).

Comment: There are multiple other solutions to detect script running as root on the question to which you referred, if that's really what you're asking.  If you are asking specifically why `$EUID` doesn't work, please edit the question to clarify the title and the body of the question, and we can re-open it

Answer (score 1):

The script `/tmp/a.sh` only works with `#!/bin/bash` on the first line.  When actually running the example I gave, the `!` was accidentally omitted and the only user reported was the non-root user as shown in the question.

Comment: Probably because without the shebang, the script was interpreted by your current shell (likely `bash`) when called without `sudo`, but was interpreted by `dash` (which doesn't set `EUID`) when called with `sudo`

Comment: @steeldriver Confirmed. On my Ubuntu  18.04 virtual machine the script with `ls -l /proc/$$/exe` reports the script is run via `/bin/dash`, however on my other debian-based  system root has `bash` as login shell and that's what is reported there. So `sudo` checks either `$SHELL` environment variable or `/etc/passwd` or other login system such as LDAP

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy it's kind of interesting that `sudo` appears to use the login shell specified in the target user's passwd entry even when not explicitly invoked with the `-i` (or `--login`) option - I'd never really thought about that before

Comment: @steeldriver Correction:  it defaults to `/bin/sh` . I've repeated the experiment couple times again: `/proc/19051/exe -> /bin/dash` is reported on both systems, so previous conclusion is mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in some of my scripts:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(id -un)" != "root" ]; then
    echo "Need root - sudoing..."
    exec sudo "$0" "$@"
fi
# Now we are root
```